# Iterating through an array in javascript + returning the sum?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

not asking you to do my homework, just kind of confused and couldn't find the solution anywhere and was wondering if you could tell me whats wrong with my code?

Question: Iterate an array
Write a function that takes an array as an argument and iterates through each member of the array and returns the sum of all the values. Being able to loop through each member of the array is extremely important. Do this over and over (under 2 minutes) before moving on to the next algorithm challenge. (Test cases: [0] returns 0, [1,2,5] returns 8, [-5,2,5,12] returns 14)

My code:

```
function iterArr(arr) {
  //your code here 
  var s = new Array();
  a[0]=0;
  a[1]=[1+2+5];
  a[2]=[-5+2+5+12];

  for (var i =0;i<s.length;i++){
    sum = sum +s;
  }
  return sum; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. This is my first time posting.

Comment: Usually the carrot(>) is used for posting errors, 4 spaces are used for posting code.

Comment: Your test cases and your code are different. Your test case states `[1,2,5]`, but your code has `[1+2+5]`. Do you see the difference? Also, your "answer" below is not an answer and should be copied into your question. Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Mike, will do in the future. Also I changed it to [1,2,5] etc and it still runs as undefined. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

So your array (s) is never initialized with anything, so the for loop will never run. Also sum is never initialized so it will return undefined. If you change the for loop to iterate over `arr.length` and initialize `sum` your code is pretty close to being done.

```js
function iterArr(arr) {
  //your code here 
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
    sum +=arr[i];
  }
  return sum; 
}

console.log(iterArr([1,2,5]));
```

Comment: wow i'm retarded. thanks for helping. i still am not sure how to get the separate test cases to run on separate lines though.

Comment: add multiple `console.log(iterArr(/**some array here**/));`